# Compute number of weeks since epoch more accurately than days/7

Tags: ios, calendar, epoch, date-arithmetic

I'm putting together a game where there's a tournament every week, and every week there's a different special bonus for the game.

To make this work I need to know which week it is so I can select the right bonus, and make sure the score goes to the right tournament.

A trivial answer is to take the number of days since epoch, offset to get to a monday, then compute the number of days and divide by 7. Obviously this fails because of leap year.

Another option would be to figure out which week of the year you're on, but that gets weird when you transition from one year to the next. Also, the tournament ends at the end of the day on Sunday, so it doesn't follow the normal week borders.

I was about to start doing some fairly complicated stuff using the year, day of year and day of week to try to figure it out, but I thought I'd ask here in case there was an easy solution I was missing.

This will be done in Objective-C on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
// Choose any reference date which is a Monday:
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *refComp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
refComp.year = 1970;
refComp.month = 1;
refComp.day = 5;
NSDate *refDate = [cal dateFromComponents:refComp];

// Compute number of weeks between your date and the reference date:
NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear fromDate:refDate toDate:yourDate options:0];
NSInteger weeks = comp.weekOfYear;
```

But calculating the number of days (since some Monday) and dividing by 7 should
give the same result because every week has 7 days, regardless of leap years.